# Why is this question appearing in my Flag Weight section?

Tags: discussion

Well I'll be honest, after looking at the question, I can't see any reason I would flag it. It also says there is -3 votes on it, but I don't have an answer on there? I don't recall flagging this.

I'm just a bit confused how this works or why this question is appearing on my flagging summary. It's a good question, no reason for me to flag it. :)

This is the question 'in question': [Allowing a user to write a post from another website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/allowing-a-user-to-write-a-post-from-another-website/7069#7069)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how it appears for you (some things look different for mods), but for me it points not to a question, but to a spam answer on that question that was deleted couple days ago.

So my guess would be that you flagged that answer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clearing that up. It just goes to the question for me, but it makes sense why. :)